# Google Maps Version 2 - Updating information windows

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

As we know in google maps android version 2, a custom information windows, is a view that converts to an image. Actually google aftre you return you view converts the view to a image an then show it to the info windows.

But I want to show images downloading from internet to my infowindow. Actually, I want that before that download complete show an progress bar to my infowindows and after it compeleted update info windows, by this mechanism how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Have a model object that contains int for progress and Bitmap for actual image.
- Start some kind of background operation started (e.g. [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) to download image.
- Update model's progress from `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate`.
- Update model's image from `AsyncTask.onPostExecute`.
- Have an observer for model (see [Observer partern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)).
- If you keep `AsyncTask` (or any other kind of `Thread` in `Activity` context, don't forget to `cancel` it and you may also skip observer pattern.
- Save reference to marker showing info window inside `InfoWindowAdapter.getInfoWindow`. Call it `markerShowingInfoWindow`.
- When you are notified of progress update,

call:

```
if (markerShowingInfoWindow != null && markerShowingInfoWindow.isShowingInfoWindow()) {
    markerShowingInfoWindow.showInfoWindow();
}
```

To force `InfoWindowAdapter.getInfoWindow` call and create `ViewGroup` containing `ProgressBar` and `ImageView` from progress and image values inside model.

As always, translate this into C# world.