# Actualise a Marker's window

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I am using a GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter to set the content of my marker's windows.

But the content is on the server and I am using an asynctask to get it.

The deal is that when I have the response my windows has already been created.
And if I wait the asynctask response like this: asynctask.execute(...).get() the application is freezing during the execution.

What I would like to do is to show a window with a progressBar and when I've got the server's response I remove the progressBar and actualise the content of the window.

How could I do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so use `onPreExecute` to start the progressbar and cancel it in `onPostExecute`

**Edit**

from the docs:

`The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow(). Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.`

what you are trying to do is not going to work since it is rendered as an image. the only way you can simulate this would be to constantly call `showInfoWindow()` on a progress update

take a look at this link

[Google Maps Version 2 - Updating information windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131039/google-maps-version-2-updating-information-windows)

Comment: It's not the point. The request is in a InfoWindowsAdapter.
Not in a simple fragment or activity.